# Set Masterpage from Global.asax in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to set the Masterpage property in Global.asax.

This is what I have done but I get a `NullReferenceException` on the first line. Any ideas how to do this?

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestContent(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.UI.Page page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;               

    if (Session["lang"] == "eng")
    {
        page.MasterPageFile = "SideMasterPageEng.master";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application_PreSendRequestContent is way too late in the page lifecycle to be doing this. 
The MasterPage has already been executed at this stage.

Global.asax is really a place for Application events rather than page specific. Be aware that many of the application events like Application_BeginRequest are called on any request, not just aspx Page requests. Many of these events are fired for every js script, image, css file etc that is requested.

Here is a good list of the events in Global.asax: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5771721.html

The only place that I know that you can definately change the master page is in the page Page_PreInitevent handler

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/Custom.master";
}
```

Edit:
Reading your comments, it sounds to me that you need to derive your pages from a base page which makes the change in one place.

```
using System;
namespace TestWebApplication
{
    public class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Page.MasterPageFile = "~/Custom.master";
        }
    }
}
```

Then alter all of your pages to inherit this instead of System.Web.UI.Page...

```
//public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page 
public partial class WebForm1 : PageBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thats is how I'm doing at the moment but with new pages being added all the time and as well I have changed the logic a few times in the code it is starting to be a mess updating the files and thats why I would have liked to do this just one place instead. 

I will try the PreRequestHandlerExecute and see what is happening!
thanks

Comment: See my edit. Use a base page from which all of your pages inherit

Comment: Ok thats is brilliant! 10 up votes from me for that. I did find a way to do this in Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute but other problems did show up. The session variable I have set is not yet updated, it does execute after this event.. but this code were needed to not catch every event.

 if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState) 
{
//Code
}

Comment: I have one masterpage nested with another on and then my aspx file who now inherits my PageBase class but it does never trigger the Page_PreInit. Does masterpages override pre inits maybe?

Comment: Sorry that was me being stupid :). Had an empty PreInit in my code.. Thanks for the help, now I have a really nice solution with way less code!